# How to return a result of xmltypes in Oracle stored procedure

Tags: xml, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have stored procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE udp_get_employeeaddress ( result_set out sys_refcursor )
AS
BEGIN
   open result_set for
   select xmlcolumn from employees where rownum < 3;

END udp_get_employees;
```

When I execute this sp, the following is returned in Output Variables in SQL Developer

XML_COLUMN

---

oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleSQLXML@49e57334

Taking out the SELECT statement only

```
select xmlcolumn from employees where rownum < 3;
```

Returns the xml result

XML_COLUMN

---

The table is defined as this:

```
CREATE TABLE "EMP"."Employees"
  (
    "ID"              NUMBER,
    "XML_COLUMN" "XMLTYPE"
  )
  xmltype column "XML_COLUMN" STORE AS BINARY XML
  xmlschema "http://www.web.com/emp.xsd"
  element "root"
```

I'm hoping for my stored procedure to return the same (resultset) as the standalone query.

This is my first foray to Oracle / xml db, as I've been primarily SQL Server DB Developer. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

**UPDATED**: Table definition/query results

Comment: What do you mean by 'not the same result'? If you're just getting different rows back, that might be because neither statement has an `order by` clause.

Comment: What results are you getting, and what results did you expect?  We have no visibility on your data - please edit your post and provide additional information.

Comment: Hi @AlexPoole it's just a sample butwhy should "order by" be needed here?

Essentially when you execute just the SELECT statement it'll return xml, when that sp is executed it returns jdbc.type in Output Variables tab in SQL Dev.

Comment: I've added an answer about what SQL Developer is doing, but as a side issue; if your `employees` table has more than two rows, your `rownum < 3` clause means it will pick two of them essentially at random. The `rownum` filters on the order Oracle happens to return the rows in. You'd probably get the same two if you run the `select` and the procedure close together, and it might usually do what you expect, but nothing is guaranteed and it'll break one day. You must specify an `order by` clause to be sure you get the rows you expect,  and a consistent result.

Comment: As another aside, creating objects with mixed case names, like `"Employees"`, is not recommended and will probably cause you pain at some point. You have to refer to the object in double-quotes and with exactly the same case everywhere; whereas if you just call it `EMPLOYEES` it will be case-insensitive and quotes aren't needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't a problem with your procedure, but seems to be an oddity with how SQL Developer is shooing the output variable - I can't see a way to show the actual content of that in that tab.

As an alternative you can see the procedure is working by calling it from an SQL Worksheet (running as a script (F5)):

```
var rc refcursor;
exec udp_get_employeeaddress(:rc);
print :rc;
```

Comment: Nice one, thanks @Alex... I guess the confusion stems from the fact that I'm used to SQL Management Studio in getting the results in one place (one way)